# Функция, которая парсит json файлы и создает новый json файл по уникальному ключу

Tags: python, json

Мне надо реализовать функцию parse(out_file, *in_files) для создания файла, который будет содержать только уникальные записи (уникальные по ключу "name") путем слияния информации из всех input_files (если мы найдем пользователя с уже существующим именем из предыдущего файла, мы должны игнорировать его).

Мой код выглядит следующим образом:

```
def parse(out_file, *in_files):
    result = []
    for files in input_files:
        with open(files, 'r') as infile:
            data = json.load(infile)
        for item in data:
            if dict(item)["name"] not in result:
                result.extend(item)
            else:
                continue

    with open(out_file, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(result, outfile)


parse("user3.json", "user1.json", "user2.json")
```

Я застрял на моменте проверки уникального ключа и мой список выводиться только с названиями ключей. Идея была в том, чтобы сначала вычитать два json файла, а потом искать уникальные записи по ключу "name" и записывать их в переменную result, а после сконвертировать result в json файл.

К примеру есть следующие два файла:

```
user1.json : 
[{"name": "Bob1", "rate": 1, “languages": ["English"]},
{"name": "Bob2", "rate":0.78, "languages": ["English", "French"]}
]

user2.json : 
[{"name": "Bob1", "rate": 25, “languages": ["French"]},
{"name": "Bob3", "rate": 78, "languages": ["Germany"]}
]
```

Результат должен быть следующим:

```
[{"name": "Bob1", "rate": 1, “languages": ["English"]},
{"name": "Bob2", "rate":0.78, "languages": ["English", "French"]}
{"name": "Bob3", "rate": 78, "languages": ["Germany"]}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собирайте ваши словари в словарь с ключом `name`. Примерно так:

```
lists = [
[{"name": "Bob1", "rate": 1, "languages": ["English"]},
{"name": "Bob2", "rate":0.78, "languages": ["English", "French"]}
],
[{"name": "Bob1", "rate": 25, "languages": ["French"]},
{"name": "Bob3", "rate": 78, "languages": ["Germany"]}
]
]

result = {}
for data in lists:
    for item in data:
        name = item['name']
        if name not in result:
            result[name] = item
result = list(result.values())
result
```

Вывод:

```
[{'name': 'Bob1', 'rate': 1, 'languages': ['English']},
 {'name': 'Bob2', 'rate': 0.78, 'languages': ['English', 'French']},
 {'name': 'Bob3', 'rate': 78, 'languages': ['Germany']}]
```

Comment: в примере как у Вас работает, поскольку все словари находятся в виде list в переменной lists, а в моем примере в переменной data два отдельных словаря в виде list. При попытке их сконкатенировать ошибка: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'

Comment: @Владимир Отнюдь! В `data` у меня именно ваши два словаря получаются. А где конкатенирование? Ни в вашем ни в моём коде вроде бы нет конкатенирования. Хотя у вас есть `extend`, я сейчас не соображу насчёт него что-то, почему там не `append`.

Comment: а каким образом мне получить переменную lists, если на вход придут другие два json файла? Я имею ввиду как их соединить ведь по сути эта конструкция for files in input_files: with open(files, 'r') as infile:
data = json.load(infile) вычитывает мои файлы и в data сохраняет результат. 
По поводу конкатенации, то я у себя в IDE пробовал, поскольку увидел у Вас переменную lists и хотел соединить два списка.

Comment: я просто изначально пробовал по вашему решению перебирать for item in data:
            for elem in item:
                name = elem["name"]
                if name not in result:
                    result[name] = elem;
    result = list(result.values()). И мне прилетает ошибка: name = elem["name"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: мне ведь в параметр *in_files приходит два отдельных json файла

Comment: разобрался, всё работает. Мне сначала просто надо было с помощью append добавить данные с двух файлов в переменную lists. И дальше уже Ваш код работает. Спасибо)

Comment: Ну хоть так. Хотя и без этого должно работать, но мне дальше лень разбираться )